# Why the process of sleep command is always in sleep status?

Tags: bash, unix, process

Why the process of sleep command is always in sleep status ?
Sleep status means waiting for I/O right ?

Comment: sleep status could be waiting for anything

Comment: It is my understanding that while a thread may sleep while a DMA request is pending, there are other reasons for a process to go into a sleep state.

Answer (score 1):

It would be misleading if a call to to the `sleep` (or associated) function were to report a process state other than *sleep*.  The `sleep` command calls the `sleep` (or associated, such as `nanosleep`) function, and as such, is in the same state as any other sleeping process.